Xscreensaver settings in Ubuntu 24.04
using Ubuntu 24.04LTS on Wayland, and have latest xscreensaver installed (6.08).
However it won't ever launch the window so I can change settings - any idea how to launch settings, or using terminal to change settings? Seems to be using setting from original install under 20.04...
Also, the screensaver will just launch after about 30 minutes even though I'm using the mouse/keyboard, but will quit when I begin to use mouse or keyboard... unstable, yep, but any workarounds?
Is there really some 'Wayland version' called wscreensaver?!?

It's xscreensaver. It doesn't work on wayland.
